# `firebase-admin` ModuleNotFound on import

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-admin

As detailed on the [GoogleCloudPlatform Github issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/5850), the following fails with a `ModuleNotFound`:

```
$ virtualenv env
$ env/bin/pip install firebase-admin google-cloud-storage
$ env/bin/python -c 'from firebase_admin import storage'
Traceback ... ModuleNotFoundError
```

Cross-posting here for visibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that `PYTHONPATH` included `.../google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/`.

Removing AppEngine from the `PYTHONPATH` resolved the problem.